# Understanding "Too many ancestors" from pylint

Tags: python, pylint

example.py:

```
'''
demo too many ancestors 
'''
from flask_security.forms import RegisterForm
from wtforms.fields import TextField

class ExtendedRegisterForm(RegisterForm):
    '''An extended register form'''
    name = TextField('Name', [])
```

When I run pylint:

```
$ pylint -r n example.py
************* Module example
R:  7, 0: Too many ancestors (10/7) (too-many-ancestors)
```

What does this mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: Whether this advice makes any sense is highly context-specific... In this specific case, I'd say there's nothing to fix. In general, always take the output of these style-checkers with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From documentation here: https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/technical_reference/features.html

> too-many-ancestors (R0901):   Too many ancestors (%s/%s) Used when
>   class has too many parent classes, try to reduce this to get a simpler
>   (and so easier to use) class.

Answer (score 49):

The problem is that you inherit from a class which has itself (too) many ancestors: RegisterForm. In your case, you can't do a lot about this, beside stopping using it which is probably not an option. So you may want to disable this message for this class, eg:

```
class ExtendedRegisterForm(RegisterForm): # pylint: disable=too-many-ancestors
```

Comment: Then, if you run Pep 8 'E261 / at least two spaces before inline ' ha ha

Answer (score 24):

In addition to the disabling directives in the source code, you can configure this through the --max-parents= commandline option. You can also specify this in the config file (.pylintrc):

```
[DESIGN]
max-parents=15
```

As you can see I set it to 15 as many classes in Django (my project), particularly its view classes, will have hierarchies that are deeper than the default 7.

Comment: prospector: error: unrecognized arguments: --max-parents=15

Comment: I just verified that it works at my end -- both the command line option as well as the config file setting. What version of pylint are you using? Mine's 1.6.5, running on Python 2.7.6 code.

Comment: I just added django in uses section and didn't care more about too-many-ancestors.

Comment: I suppose you sorted out your issues. However what you did is not clear to me. It'll be great if you can share the solution, time permitting of course. Tks.

Answer (score 2):

basically Add to json or .pylintrc `--max-parents='yourrequirednumber'`

Note: `--max-parents=7` is default

If using Visual Studio Code (VSC) you can easily override default config with adding
below code to settings.json

Go to --> UserSettings `ctrl+,` (default shortcut) --> click ... (more actions) --> open settings.json --> Add to overwrite Default settings this code:

`"python.linting.pydocstyleArgs": ["--max-parents=25"]`

NOTE2:
if pylint_django is not installed:
`$ pip install pylint-django`